# Pager images appear vertical - not horizontal in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

Hi I am using the module views-slideshow.I created the view and take the format slideshow.It's working.There are 5 images in the slideshow.I used pager in bottom widget and take the pager fields as small images.But pager fields is showing as vertical not horizontal.Please help me how to show any fields as horizontal in pager fields.Sorry for  mistakes in written english.
Thanks

Comment: most probably it can be fixed by giving `width="auto"` on the pager element. now the exact div that needs to be targeted should be found using trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my own opinion is not to use predefined views slideshow styles,
choose no-style or make your own style, add your custom css.
this is the best way of how to do it, otherwise you will face a little problems like this one